# Import-Export images to planes not working

Tags: image

I want to import an image as a plane, but when I go to download the addon, it doesn't come up.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried installing the addon manually? I'm not sure why it doesn't show up, so I went ahead and got the addon for you from my addons folder, try installing it as an external addon to see if it works https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FlUA9t1jur1BGJm_8ABI1kJeMC2xL33I/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It seems to work fine, thank you so much!